# C# DataGridView - Call sort from CellEndEdit event

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, datagridviewtextboxcell

At the moment I am using `this.EndInvoke(this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker( this.resortRows )));` to call the method that checks for empty cells and then sorts the DGV. But I am calling this from CellEndEdit.

Everything works fine if the event is called by pressing Enter or Tab, but If I click on another cell while still in EditMode I get an error on the line with the sort command:

```
Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.
```

This is the Sort command:

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

I tried to hande the `MouseClick` event like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
}
```

But this works only if I click inside the DGV on the grey area (Not on any cell or header).
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually tried your code and it seems that the problem is `EndInvoke`.
Just remove it (i.e. use only `BeginInvoke`) and it will work fine.

**EDIT :**

Using `BeginInvoke` without `EndInvoke` the invoked method will be executed just after `CellEndEdit` handler exits.

If you need to call a code after each sorting, just put it at the end of the invoked method.

Comment: this means I have to rewrite half of my class. :(
Rethink everything.

Comment: This does not sort automatically. It just displays a small triangle indicating the sorting direction.

Comment: Strange, it works for me... as soon as I edit one cell the column is automatically sorted...

Comment: I need EndInvoke there, otherwise it will execute `resortRows` far to late. I need `resortRows` to execute as soon as EndEdit is done (or before that if it can).

Comment: I tried removing my sort command and it still did not work, maybe something else interferes with it. I'll run a few tests.

Comment: Found my problem and a Fix. I wasn't using any `DataSource`. So I implemented an `DataTable`. Now the sorting is done automatically.

Comment: @ovidiub13: oh, that's the difference between your tests and mine ! I used datatable in my tests :)

Comment: Is there an Event that can capture the moment after this sorting happens? `private void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)` is called only when you sort by clicking on the column headers.

Comment: @ovidiub13: I doubt it exists. But I'm still convinced that you should get rid of EndInvoke and simply use your previous code. If you have only one thread, the sorting will be called just after CellEndEdit handler exits... however you should fully describe what you're trying to accomplish to get an useful help.

Comment: I need a way to call a method After the sorting is done automatically, after a cell has been edited. I got rid of EndInvoke and of BeginInvoke. I'm trying again from scratch.

Comment: @ovidiub13: IMO you should: handle CellEndEdit, inside this handler call your sort method using _only_ BeginInvoke(yourSort), and at the end of your sorting method just put the method you need to call after sorting...